# Prove If $A$ nilpotent matrix $\implies det(A)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Let $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&3\\ 0&0&4\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

1) prove the B is nilpotent and find the minimum $k\ge1$ so that $B^k=0$

2) Prove If $A$ nilpotent matrix $\implies det(A)=0$

---

for (1) its easy to see that :

$$B^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&4\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

and $$B^3=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

so the minimum $k$ is $k=3$ , but How to prove that its nilpotent ?

---

for (2)

$$0=det(0)=det(A^k)=det(A)^k$$

is this enough to prove if $A$ nilpotent matrix $\implies det(A)=0$?

thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, your proof of (2) works.

Comment: @Paul  thanks . but for (1) is there any way to prove that $B$ nilpotent ?

Comment: @eeewww You just did it. Show that $B^k=0$ for some $k$ is the definition of nilpotent.

Comment: oh okey thanks a lot

Comment: If $A$ is a  nilpotent matrix so its eigenvalue is $0$. $det(A)=0$so